What's the cleanest way to know when the <slot /> child is mounted?
I want to call a function once my slot child is mounted.
This function is supposed to deplace the child element (using GSAP). I tried to add a nextTick() inside my onMounted but my function returns an error saying my child doesn't exist yet. If I add a setTimeout before calling my function it works correctly but I'd like to avoid this kind of solution.
<template>
    <div>
      <div ref="el">
        <slot />
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

const el = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        if (el.value.children.length > 0) {
            observer.disconnect()

            myMethod();
        }
    })
    observer.observe(el.value, { childList: true })
})
</script>

I thinks the issue happen because my child component has a v-if condition that's set to true once a computed() call is return :
// CHILD COMPONENT
<template>
    <div
        v-if="currentData"
    >
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        items: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
    });
    const currentData = computed(() => props.items[0]);
</script>

So far I only manage to get what I want by using a MutationObserver().
I tried to watch the slot but my console.log is never called :
// NOT WORKING
const slots = useSlots();
watch(
    () => slots.default(), 
    () => {
        nextTick(() => {
            console.log('test')
        }) 
    }
)

How can I refactor this by using nuxt3 methods ?
Thank you very much

Consider explaining your case. Is a child provided unconditionally? What does myMethod do? Generally it's nextTick inside onMounted

@EstusFlask context added!

Please, provide a way to reproduce. Generally it's supposed to work. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hcjxxw

@EstusFlask i just detailed the condition in my child component

That a child doesn't have root element at some point doesn't look good, this looks like a problem with design, it's actually the case for MutationObserver because you blackboxed "currentData" condition. Afaik slots aren't officially reactive in vue 3 but it's possible to do watch(() => slots.default(), () => { nextTick(() => {  myMethod()  } }). A proper way would probably to use  suspense, so a parent isn't mounted until a child is ready.

@EstusFlask thanks for your answer, I updated my question after  I tried to watch the slot but it doesn't seem to work.

I see. It would likely work if v-if="condition" were used directly in the slot but the watcher cannot handle the whole component hierarchy. Then I'd suggest suspense. It's unknown why items[0] changes with time, usually this means that it's async op that stands behind its change that needs to be waited

Something about this implementation doesn't make sense, a component is considered mounted when all it's synchronous child components are mounted, so child components onMounted() hooks are called first, then the parent component's onMounted hook is called second. If the child has <Suspense /> then this logic reverses.

In your example it appears the logic should be moved up since the slot content belongs to the parent so the logic should probably be handled in the parent. You seem to be trying to react to the slot content in the child when it belongs to the parent which doesn't make sense here.
